# Trouble with unitialized pointer

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments

I'm having a little trouble with pointers. I know that it's probably some silly mistake by me, but I could use some help right now.

I'm making a program which has some command line arguments and I decided to 
make a function called `get_param(...)` so that i don't have a ton of lines in my main for this purpose.

Here is the prototype for this function

```
bool get_param(int argc, char **argv, char *fname);
```

In this example I just work with one argument. My program is supposed to be called like this `./voter -i voters.txt`, where voters.txt is just a file I will be using later.

In my main function I create a variable `char *fname`for the file of the name, and then I call `get_param(argc, argv, fname)`.

The output I get is

```
-i = randomfile.txt
-i = (null)
```

Why is that? I dynamically allocate space for `fname` in `get_param`, so isn't that space supposed to 'stay' even after my function gets to its end?

Below is my code.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

bool get_param(int argc, char **argv, char *fname);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *fname;

    if (get_param(argc, argv, fname) == false)
        return -1;

    printf("-i = %s\n", fname);

    return 0;
}

bool get_param(int argc, char **argv, char *fname){

    if (argc != 3){
        printf("%s: wrong number of inline parameters\n", *argv);
        return false;
    }

    char i[] = "-i";
    if (strcmp(argv[1], i) == 0){
        fname = (char *)malloc((strlen(argv[2]) + 1)*sizeof(char));
        assert(fname != NULL);
        strcpy(fname, argv[2]);
        printf("-i = %s\n", fname);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        printf("%s: %s: no such parameter\n", *argv, argv[1]);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need all this rigmarole? You already have the filename in `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

The copy of `fname` in `get_param` is strictly local to `get_param`.  It's initialized to the value passed in from `main` (i.e., undefined), but that's all.  If you want to update the value of `fname` in main, then you need to pass the address, then update it in `get_param`.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the code to 
bool get_param(int argc, char **argv,  **char **fname**);

change the call to get_param(argc, argv, fname)
to get_param(argc, argv, **&fname**)

and inside get_param use ***fname** everywhere you use fname inside function.